# org-mode saving buffer has long delay, how to tune it?

Tags: org-mode

I'm using emacs "25.0.92.1", with Prelude customization on Windows 7. I mainly use org-mode.
I found that org-mode takes long delay to save buffer `(save-buffer)`, as long as the edit is more than 
several dozen characters. It may take as long as 10 seconds, not able to continue editing.

I tried even with emacs -Q, it will still takes about 5 seconds.

(I also noticed that it takes long time to open and load org file.)

The file in question has about 500 lines, some of the lines may be long of about 200 hundred characters.

I also tried to increase gc-cons-threshold, but seems not effect.

I only have last option to go back to version 24.x to try my luck.

Could you please your insights or experience.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Try to profile your emacs configurations as follows:

1. Run `M-x profiler-start`
2. Edit your `.org` file for a while;
3. Run `M-x profiler-report` to see the detailed time consumption of each function;
4. Locate the package which the function that takes the most CPU time belongs to;
5. Uninstall the package or comment out the configurations of that specific package

Comment: I noticed that it's being block, thus not necessarily using CPU, thus profiler-report would not much clue.

Comment: Maybe some other processes take up your system disk IO? Try kill other irrelevant processes in your task manager.